# Pretty printing polynomials in IPython notebook

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have some polynomial `x` in IPython notebook:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial([1,2,3])
x
```

Then `x` is printed as `Polynomial([ 1.,  2.,  3.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])` which is to be honest ugly. How can I have normal printing like I'm rendering the polynomial in LaTeX or writing it on paper?

Comment: Numpy 1.16 will latex-format the polynomial for you out of the box

Answer (score 3):

You can use sympy's Poly class to render your polynomials to nice latex.
The only issue here, is that numpy lists the coefficients in order of increasing degree, whereas sympy does the opposite.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: nppoly = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial([1,2,3])
   ...: nppoly
Out[1]: Polynomial([ 1.,  2.,  3.], [-1.,  1.], [-1.,  1.])

In [2]: import sympy as sp
   ...: from sympy.abc import x
   ...: sp.init_printing()
   ...: sp.Poly(reversed(nppoly.coef),x).as_expr()
```

which gives:
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can always retrieve the coefficients of a polynomial object using the `polynomial_obj.coef` which returns a numpy array and then you can just play around with it to get the desired output.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial([1,2,3])

def get_prettified_output(polynomial):
    prettified_output = ""
    coefficients = polynomial.coef
    for i in xrange(len(coefficients)):
        prettified_output+= str(coefficients[i])+"*x**"+str(i)+" + "
    return prettified_output[:-2]

print get_prettified_output(x)
```

However, you can also use something like `prettified_output+= str(polynomial.coef[i])+"*x^"+str(i)+" + "` or something more convenient.

Comment: Not really what  I'm looking for. More link when you write $x^2$ in LaTeX i renders into nice text.

Comment: I said that you can modulate the output the way you want, But this thing can give you a start

Answer (score 0):

IPython has [an example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3607712653c66d63e0d7f13f073bde8c0f209ba8/docs/examples/notebooks/display_protocol.ipynb) of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without aiming at a LaTeX output in a IPython notebook, I wrote [this small overload](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/lbesson/j6dpz#file-nicedisplay_numpy_polynomial_Polynomial.py) of the [numpy.polynomial.Polynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.html) class in order to nicely display a Polynomial object :

```
>>> P = MyPolynomial  # The custom class, with a modified __str__ method
>>> X = P([0, 1])     # We define the monome X, to write polynomials simply
>>> Q1 = 1 + 2*X + 17*X**3  # Example of a polynomial
>>> # Was displayed poly([1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 17.0]) before... ugly!
>>> print(Q1)  # Way nicer now!
1 + 2 * X + 17 * X**3
```

By adding a similar `_repr_latex_` method, as explained [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html#IPython.core.formatters.LatexFormatter), for IPython, you could do the same (just change the `**` symbols to `^` and remove the `*`, you will get LaTeX code).